# How can I set a custom seekbar's ProgressDrawable size to be smaller than the ProgressBackground

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom `seekbar` that's not quite working.

I want the `seekbar` to look like this:

[image: Notice the progress bar is 'skinnier' than the background]

But this is as close as I have been able to get

[image: The progress bar and background are the same size]

Ignoring the slight coloring and size issues, the problem I'm having is with the green `progress` size. Is there some way to make this smaller than the background? I've tried `size` and `padding` tags in the `XML`, and even tried fiddling with two rectangles on top of each other with clip `gravity`, but no luck yet.

Here is my `Seekbar` drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/fofo_grey" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="20dp" />
                  <solid android:color="@color/signup_green" />
            </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And the Seekbar in the layout fragment

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:splitTrack="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="50"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
```

Comment: SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setScaleY(2f);
        seekBar.setScaleX(2f);

Comment: No luck here I'm afraid, this has just made the whole `Seekbar` huge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/fofo_grey" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">

        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
                  <solid android:color="@color/signup_green" />
                <stroke android:width="6dp"
                        android:color="@color/fofo_grey" />
            </shape>
    </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

***just add stroke attribute in seekbar drawable***

Comment: Thanks David, came to this solution in my own answer. I'll mark yours as accepted though, since you were on the money.

Comment: I write this same code but progressDrawable not changed what will do?

Answer (score 30):

for change height progress drawble just add `android:minHeight="2dp"` and `android:maxHeight="2dp"` to layout.

**UPDATE:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:minHeight="2dp"
    android:maxHeight="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/sb_progress_drawable"
    android:progress="0"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:thumbOffset="0dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/sb_thumb" />
```

sb_progress_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#26FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:scaleWidth="100%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#26FFFFFF"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:scaleWidth="100%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

sb_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Comment: What is pseekbar xml?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, not sure why it has so many votes.

Answer (score 13):

Managed to fix this. Can't believe it took me so long to think of the solution...

```
<clip>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="@color/fofo_grey" android:width="6dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/signup_green" />
    </shape>
</clip>
```

Added a `stroke` with the same colour as the background element, and tweaked the `stroke` `width` to achieve the desired effect.

[image: Finished effect]

Comment: Wow! Nice catch! Thanks.